# Combination of A B C D with condition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How can I arrange $A, B, C, D$ in two by two blocks where in each combination I need to have the four elements.
I know the answer is 3 $(AB CD , AC BD , AD BC)$ but I don't know how to solve it using a formula or by generalizing it by taking into account the number of elements, the two by two, and the necessity to have 4 elements in each combination.

Comment: Observe that once you assign a match for $A$, you are done.  $A$ has $3$ possible matches, $B$, $C$, or $D$.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can count the number of ways to choose $2$ out of $4$ elements, which really picks both pairs: the two you choose, and the two unchosen. That number is given by:

$$\binom42=\frac{4!}{2!2!}=\frac{4\cdot 3}{2\cdot 1} = 6$$

Now, counting this way, you will have counted $AB,CD$ separately from $CD,AB$, but you want those to be the same. Thus, you divide by $2$ to compensate for double-counting:

$$\frac62=3$$

---

Edit: in response to the follow-up question, if we want to choose three pairs from $\{A,B,C,D\}$ so that no two pairs have the full set as their union, but all three pairs do, such as $\{A,B\},\{A,C\},\{A,D\}$, then there are only four ways to do it.

If the first pair is $AB$, then the second pair must repeat one of those letters, suppose it repeats $A$, so let it be $AC$. The third pair now must include $D$, but it cannot be $BD$ or $CD$, because either of those would make a complete set together with $AC$ or $AB$ respectively. Thus, $AD$ has to be the fourth choice.

Once we decided which letter would repeat, all other choices were forced or else irrelevant. Thus, there are four ways to do this: one with $A$ in each pair, one with $B$ in each pair, one with $C$ in each pair, and one with $D$ in each pair.

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I now combine them Two by Tow but this time all the elements A B C D must appear in three combinations and not in just two, like (AB AC AD, AB AC BD, ....) and not (AB CD BC,...).

Comment: I don't think I understand this second question. How is $AB,AC,BD$ acceptable?

Comment: It's acceptable because A B C  and D appear all in the combination of those three pairs and not only in just two. So for example D is missing in AB AC and C is missing in AB BD but all the elements are present in AB, AC, BD. The four elements must appear in the combination of three pairs and not in two.

Comment: I see.... so any two pairs fail to include all 4 elements, but the three pairs together include them?

Comment: That example still doesn't work, because the $B$ is not missing in $AC, BD$.

Comment: Exactly, two pairs fail to include all the 4 elements and we need three pairs .

Comment: Yes the example is not correct, I modified it.

Comment: I've edited my answer to cover this case now.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any possibility to formulate it as an equation like the first problem?

Comment: I don't think there would be something as nice for the second one. Once you reason through what the "shape" of a solution has to be, then counting them is simply a matter of $\binom41=4$.

Comment: Thank you very much I really appreciate your help, many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are $\binom 42$ ways to choose the first pair.  Choosing the first pair determines the second.

That's not quite the full story though, choosing the pair $AB$ is the same as choosing the pair $CD$ (as the groupings $\{AB,CD\}$ and $\{CD,AB\}$ are the same.  More generally, we have to divide by $2$ to cancel the symmetry between the first pair and the second.  Thus the answer is $$\frac 12 \times \binom 42=3$$

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I now combine them Two by Tow but this time all the elements A B C D must appear in three combinations and not in just two, like (AB AC AD, AB AC BD, ....) and not (AB CD BC,...).

Comment: I don't understand the new condition.

Comment: The new condition is two pairs shouldn't include all the elements while three pairs do.

Comment: But then your second example, $\{AB,AC,BD\}$ fails as $\{AC,BD\}$ has all three

Comment: Yes, it's AB AC BC instead.

Comment: That still doesn't work (no $D$).